# how to write a function in python to sum up a given set of numbers other than itself?

Tags: python, list, indexing

how to write a function in python to sum up a given set of numbers other than itself

**Input:** An array of n integers nums,

**Output:** An array output such that output[i] is equal to the sum of all the elements of nums except nums[i].

*For example, given [1,2,3,4], return [9,8,7,6].*

Comment: As per the wordings of your question, if the input list is `[1,2,3,1,4,3]` with the `sum = 14`, the output should be `[13, 12, 11, 13, 10, 11]` because you *specifically* mentioned **except nums[i]** where `i` is a specific index. The answers provided below, however, gives the output as `[12, 12, 8, 12, 10, 8]`. Which one of them do you want?

Comment: @Bazingaa , yes I want the answer [13, 12, 11, 13, 10, 11] and the answers provided below gives me the same answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers have ignored the possibility of there being duplicates of the same number:

```
def sum_neighbours(li): ## Renamed list to li as list is already a python keyword so shouldn't be used as you may accidentally shadow it and have problems
    return [sum(li) - (li.count(num) * num) for num in li]
```

If performance is a key factor:

```
def sum_neighbours(li):
    s = sum(li) ## Precompute the sum so that it doesn't need to be recalculated in every iteration
    return [s - (li.count(num) * num) for num in li]
```

If duplicates don't affect your sum:

```
    return [sum(li) - num for num in li]
```

Also, if your input list is always going to be similar to [1, 2, 3, ..., n], then the calculation of the sum can be optimised by `s = (s * (s + 1)) / 2` as this will save the program from having to add each number in the list.

Comment: you gave the first solution which dealt the duplication problem and so I give it to you.

Comment: @AhamedMoosa Thanks! Would asking for an upvote be too much? ;)

Comment: That goes without saying.I upvote your answer and also marked it as the right answer. Thanks buddy.

Comment: @AhamedMoosa Didn't know that was you! No problem :)

Comment: Your code gives `[12, 12, 8, 12, 10, 8]` as output if you take `[1,2,3,1,4,3]` as input. Try running it. The OP mentioned in the comments below the question that for `[1,2,3,1,4,3]` as input, the output should be  `[13, 12, 11, 13, 10, 11]`.

Comment: @Bazingaa I've addressed that. Also, the OP also states that my solution works perfectly for him as desired.

Comment: Considering what OP told me and what he/she wrote about solution working perfectly, it seems the OP is unclear in the desired output. Anyway, just wanted to make sure which output OP wants.

Comment: @Bazingaa I understand where you're coming from. You're right, but who am I to argue? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit more pythonic:

```
 def sum_neighbors(_list):
     s = sum(_list)
     return [s - item for item in _list]
```

Or, if you dare:

```
 def sum_neighbors(_list):
     s = sum(_list)
     return list(map(operator.sub, itertools.repeat(s), _list))
```

To address duplicates:

```
def sum_neighbors(_list):
    counts = collections.Counter(_list)
    s = sum(_list)
    return [s - counts[item] * item for item in _list]
```

Tip: I've renamed `list` to `_list` so you don't shadow the builtin `list` type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will take the first answer as it is more simple and understandable :)

Comment: @AhamedMoosa What if you have duplicate numbers: `[1,1,2]`?

Comment: @ReutSharabani I've addressed that in my answer.

Comment: @Adi219 I really think a `collections.Counter` is the way to go in that case.

Comment: @ReutSharabani , I believe the solution still works , I tried my_list_3 = [2,2,4,5] and I got [11, 11, 9, 8]

Comment: @AhamedMoosa I've expanded my answer to address whatever you may have meant.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Thanks for the expansion and the logical explanation , however I have to give it to Adi , as he came up with the solution without I mentioning the duplication issue. Thank again

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to use this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
result = [sum(a)-i for i in a]
```

Output:

```
[9, 8, 7, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def add_func(lst):
      return list(sum(lst)-i for i in lst))

print(add_func([1,2,3,4]))
```